# Sparfun XBee USB Serial adapter & Mac OS X El Capitan not working

Tags: macos, serial-port, xbee

Tried to use my sparkfun Xbee serial adapter with El Capitan, reinstalled the FTDI driver but i´m not able to get contact to the adapter via serial interface.

Doe´s anyone has an idea how to enable FTDI support on El Capitan?

Comment: Why do you assume that the FTDI driver is the problem?  You should try a simple loopback test.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Does it work on other computers?  Was it working with that computer before installing El Capitan?

Comment: It hat worked before and with el capitan i am not able to even see the device within the /dev dir. Found a couple of sites who describe the same problem. Asked yesterday at the sparksfun forum and they confirmed that El Capitan seems to have broken the FTDI driver. https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=42102